# How to generate checksum for a file whose content is stored as image type in database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the documents stored in SQL Server 2008 table, whose contents are of type `image`. I want to generate a checksum for every file in C# so that I can determine which files are the same.

I know how to generate checksum if we have the whole file (with file type), nut I am not getting how to generate checksum when we have file content as `image` type in SQL.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Have a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: are you wanting this on the database side, or the c# side?

Answer (score 0):

You can either generate your checksum in your C# program and store it to the DB manually. Or you generate the checksum in the DB (obvously). From SQL server 2008 you can generate a hash with the [`HASHBYTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174415.aspx) function:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', t.ImageColumn)
FROM MyTable t
```

You could even create a computed column to create an automatic hash value:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Image VARBINARY(MAX),
    ImageHash AS HASHBYTES('SHA1', Image)
)
```

If you want to trade `SELECT` performance (faster) with `INSERT` performance (slower), you can persist your computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Image VARBINARY(MAX),
    ImageHash AS HASHBYTES('SHA1', Image) PERSISTED
)
```

Comment: Content is my column with image data type.

Comment: I tried like SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', t.Content)
FROM Emission.Document t where t.Id = 1;

Comment: I get this message Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Argument data type image is invalid for argument 2 of hashbytes function.

Comment: Check the link I provided you. The data type must be varchar, nvarchar or varbinary. Convert if necessary.

Comment: You should not use image as a column type anyway. [It's deprecated.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem? Then you should accept it.

Comment: Did you? Click the grey checkmark next to the question and it will turn green then you did accept. And then click the help link on the top right of the page.

Comment: Also, what should be the datatype to store the checksum in SQl Server table.

Comment: Check the link I have provided you. And for a persisted column you don't need to specify a data type. It is implicit.